Pandas dataframe groupby apply function with variable number of arguments
I have a pandas dataframe that looks like
import pandas as pd

data = {
  "Race_ID": [2,2,2,2,2,5,5,5,5,5,5],
  "Student_ID": [1,2,3,4,5,9,10,2,3,6,5],
  "theta": [8,9,2,12,4,5,30,3,2,1,50]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

and I have a function f(thetai, *theta) = thetai ** 2 + the other thetas in the same race which I want to apply to the theta column in dataframe grouped by Race_ID and create a new column called feature.
So we have
For student 1 in Race 2, the value is 8^2 + 9+2+12+4
For student 2 in Race 2, the value is 9^2 + 8+2+12+4
For student 3 in Race 2, the value is 2^2 + 8+9+12+4
etc.
I know about the groupby and apply methods but I don't know how to apply the methods when the number of arguments can vary.
So the desired outcome looks like
data = {
  "Race_ID": [2,2,2,2,2,5,5,5,5,5,5],
  "Student_ID": [1,2,3,4,5,9,10,2,3,6,5],
  "theta": [8,9,2,12,4,5,30,3,2,1,50],
  "fearure": [91,107,37,167,47,111,961,97,93,91,2541]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

Edit: My actual function f for my problem is actually a lot more complicated, I was just using the example here to demonstrate the main hurdle, namely the variable argument problem. Here is my actual function f:
def integrand(xi, thetai, *theta):
  S = 0
  for tj in theta:
    prod = 1
    for t in theta:
      if abs(t - tj) < 1e-10:
        continue
      prod = prod * (1 - norm.cdf(xi + thetai - t))
    S = S + norm.cdf(xi + thetai - tj) * prod
  return S * norm.pdf(xi)


def f(thetai, *theta):
  return (integrate.quad(integrand, -np.inf, np.inf, args=(thetai, *theta)))[0]


Just make an intermediary column of the sums of the other theta's.
theta_sum = df.groupby("Race_ID").sum()["theta"].to_dict()
# (theta sum of race_id) - self theta
df["theta_feature"] = df.apply(
    lambda x: theta_sum[x["Race_ID"]] - x["theta"], axis=1
)
df["feature"] = df.apply(
    lambda x: x["theta"] ** 2 + x["theta_feature"], axis=1
)

and then if you don't want the undesired column you can just drop it with
df.drop(columns="theta_feature", inplace=True)

Edit:- To pass the the thetas to the function (which will give a different result for the feature column as the function isn't initially described, you can do an apply with the following:-
def calc_grpd_thetas(x):
    _df = df[(df['Race_ID'] == x["Race_ID"]) & (df.index != x.name)]
    thetas = list(_df['theta'])
    return f(x["theta"], *thetas)

df["feature"] = df.apply(calc_grpd_thetas, axis=1)

which will net you this


Hi @dydev, thank you for your answer, but my actual function f(thetai, *theta) is actually a lot more complicated (it's an integral using scipy.integrate.quad) and I was just using the example here to demonstrate the main hurdle, namely the variable argument problem. I have edited the problem to include my actual function f, thank you so much for your help.

Hi, can you please include the integrand function in your edit?

Hi @dydev, I did, please see the edit, thank you so much
def integrand(xi, thetai, *theta):
  S = 0
  for tj in theta:
    prod = 1
    for t in theta:
      if abs(t - tj) < 1e-10:
        continue
      prod = prod * (1 - norm.cdf(xi + thetai - t))
    S = S + norm.cdf(xi + thetai - tj) * prod
  return S * norm.pdf(xi)


@Ishigami I've edited the post to pass the thetas to the function as described. I hope that was what you were looking for.

Use a groupby.transform with a custom function:
def f(t):
    # get sum of all
    s = t.sum()
    # sum of all - self + self^2
    # = sum of others + self^2
    return t.rsub(s).add(t**2)

df['feature'] = df.groupby('Race_ID')['theta'].transform(f)

Which is equivalent to taking the sum and adding theta*(theta-1):
df['feature'] = (df.groupby('Race_ID')['theta']
                   .transform(lambda t: t*(t-1)+t.sum())
                 )

Alternatively, with transform('sum') and performing the correction afterwards.
df['feature'] = (df.groupby('Race_ID')['theta']
                   .transform('sum')
                   .sub(df['theta'])
                   .add(df['theta']**2)
                 )

Output:
    Race_ID  Student_ID  theta  feature
0         2           1      8       91
1         2           2      9      107
2         2           3      2       37
3         2           4     12      167
4         2           5      4       47
5         5           9      5      111
6         5          10     30      961
7         5           2      3       97
8         5           3      2       93
9         5           6      1       91
10        5           5     50     2541


Hi @mozway, thank you for your answer, but my actual function f(thetai, *theta) is actually a lot more complicated (it's an integral using scipy.integrate.quad) and I was just using the example here to demonstrate the main hurdle, namely the variable argument problem. I have edited the problem to include my actual function f, thank you so much for your help.
